# Error while saving the incoming request to CoS. Details : {} com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.ResetException

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sdk

How to fix the ResetException while saving the incoming request to CoS. I'm running some load test and I started seeing this error. I ran the request with payload 5MB around 950+ times and I'm noticed this error. Error was not coming still 300 request and after that it started raising.
Out of 950 request 25 request was failed for the same reason.

```
[ERROR] [Api2ApiRest,272b4fd44d2f7e800d7eff676274c2a9,8e826c2006fb690e,ed7e779c69c3cd63] 2024-03-07 09:15:53,431 ERROR [http-nio-9443-exec-28] - Error saving the incoming request to CoS. Details : {}
com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.ResetException: The request to the service failed with a retryable reason, but resetting the request input stream has failed. See exception.getExtraInfo or debug-level logging for the original failure that caused this retry.;  If the request involves an input stream, the maximum stream buffer size can be configured via request.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(int)
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.resetRequestInputStream(AmazonHttpClient.java:1423) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1240) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxxat com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-core-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4491) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4437) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:324) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:5215) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1766) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1726) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.xxx.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1651) ~[xxx-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.11.0.jar!/:?]
```

putObject method:

```
public void putObject( String objectKey, InputStream objectData, Long contentLength )
        throws SdkClientException, AmazonS3Exception {
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength( contentLength );
        cos.putObject( cosBucketId, objectKey, objectData, metadata );
    }
```